# The listView.SeptEmptyView is always show even when there are elements in the listView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

The emptyView in a ListView is always shown even when there are records in the ListView.
I'm using SherlockFragment and I'm showing ListView the code is the following:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.header_file, hotelListView, false);
        hotelListView.addHeaderView(vg, null, false);
        hotelListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        hotelListView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty));
```

and the xml:

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/hotel_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No Results" />
```

So after I retrieve the results form the server the TextView is still shown on the screen and I can see the No Results text on screen and in the same time there are items in the list. What do I need to change so the @android:id/empty will be show only when there are no elements in the list? Thanks

Comment: I also have the same issue all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking in to the source, I can think of 3 possible mistakes,

1. ListView doesn't have the adapter set.
2. If adapter is reimplemented, is getCount() method reimplemented correctly ?
3. do you have to call notifyDatasetChanged() ? After content is fetched from server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problme whast hat I had added a new empty view in preExecute thread call